# Setting title attributes for UIBarButtonItemStyleDone using appearance proxy

Tags: ios7, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance, uibarbuttonitemstyle, uibaritem

I'm customizing my `UIBarButtonItem` buttons appearance using appearance proxy. While in the `UIBarButtonItem` class you can differentiate these buttons by button style ad you can customize all kinds of images, title position etc., you cannot customize title attributes by button style, since setTitleAttributes is the method of `UIBarItem` not that of the button. So if I would like to show bordered styled button with black title and done styled button with white title, I cannot use the appearance. Does somebody know how can I change title color for only `UIBarButtonStyleDone` buttons?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You ever get this resolved?